# Cake php Multiple model validation

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have two tables :

senderinfos :

```
  id   |   Name   | email_add |  Address   |
============================================
  1    | Amit     | 1@1.com   | park Street|
```

receiverinfos:

```
  id  |  Name  | email_add|  Address  |
=======================================
  1   |  SOS   | 2@2.com      | park1
```

I am giving the model,view,And Controller Code :

Model

Senderinfo :

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Admin Login Model
 *
 */
 class Senderinfo extends AppModel
 {
    public $name='Senderinfo';
    public $usetables='senderinfos';

    public $validate = array(


      'contact' =>
      array(
      'rule'       => 'notEmpty', // or: array('ruleName', 'param1', 'param2' ...)
      'allowEmpty' => false,
      'message'    => 'Please Enter Contact.'
      ),

     'name' =>
      array(
      'rule'       => 'notEmpty', // or: array('ruleName', 'param1', 'param2' ...)
      'allowEmpty' => false,
      'message'    => 'Please Enter Sender Name.'
      ),


     'email_add' => array(

            'email_add' => array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => 'Please Enter Valid Email',
            'last' => true
    )),


    );

 }
?>
```

Receiveinfo :

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Admin Login Model
 *
 */
 class Receiverinfo extends AppModel
 {
    public $name='Receiverinfo';
    public $usetables='receiverinfos';

    public $validate = array(


      'contact' =>
      array(
      'rule'       => 'notEmpty', // or: array('ruleName', 'param1', 'param2' ...)
      'allowEmpty' => false,
      'message'    => 'Please Enter Contact.'
      ),

     'name' =>
      array(
      'rule'       => 'notEmpty', // or: array('ruleName', 'param1', 'param2' ...)
      'allowEmpty' => false,
      'message'    => 'Please Enter Sender Name.'
      ),


     'email_add' => array(

            'email_add' => array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => 'Please Enter Valid Email',
            'last' => true
    )),


    );

 }
?>
```

View

send_money.ctp

```
<content>
            <div class="pg_title txtLeft">Send Money</div>
                <?php echo $this->Form->create('Agents', array('action' => 'send_money'));?>

                    <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method"></div>
                    <fieldset title="SENDER'S INFORMATION"><legend>SENDER'S INFORMATION</legend>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Contact No.<span class="red">*</span></label></td>
                                <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Senderinfo.contact',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'size'=>50,'style'=>'width:330px')); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Sender's Name<span class="red">*</span></label></td>
                                <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Senderinfo.name',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'size'=>50,'style'=>'width:330px')); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Email Address</label></td>
                                <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Senderinfo.email_add',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'size'=>50,'style'=>'width:330px')); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Mailing Address</label></td>
                                <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Senderinfo.address',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'type'=>'textarea','cols'=>39,'rows'=>3,'class'=>'textarea','style'=>'width:330px')); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset title=""><legend>RECEIVER'S INFORMATION</legend>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Contact No.<span class="red">*</span></label></td>
                                <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Receiverinfo.contact',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'size'=>50,'style'=>'width:330px')); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Receiver's Name<span class="red">*</span></label></td>
                                <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Receiverinfo.name',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'size'=>50,'style'=>'width:330px')); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Email Address</label></td>
                                <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Receiverinfo.email_add',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'size'=>50,'style'=>'width:330px')); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Mailing Address</label></td>
                                <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Receiverinfo.address',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'type'=>'textarea','cols'=>39,'rows'=>3,'class'=>'textarea','style'=>'width:330px')); ?></td>
                            </tr>

                            </tbody>
                    </table> 
                    </fieldset>

                     <fieldset><legend>MONEY TRANSFER</legend>
                    <table>
                        <tbody> 
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Amount(tk)<span class="red">*</span></label></td>
                                <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Transaction.sending_amount',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'size'=>50,'style'=>'width:330px')); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Charge(tk)<span class="red">*</span></label></td>
                                <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Transaction.charge',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'size'=>50,'style'=>'width:330px')); ?></td>
                            </tr>

                           <tr>
                           <?php 
                           $foo = "";
                            $options = array('1' => 'Paid','0' => ' Due');
                            $attributes = array(
                                'legend' => false,
                                'value' => true,
                                'checked'=> ($foo == "Paid"),
                            );
                            ?>
                            <td>
                             <?php echo $this->Form->radio('transaction.status',$options, $attributes);?>
                           </td>
                           </tr>


                        </tbody>
                    </table> 
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset><legend>CUSTOM MESSAGE</legend>
                    <table>
                        <tbody> 
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 158px;"><label>Message</label></td>
                                <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('transaction.message',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'type'=>'textarea','cols'=>39,'rows'=>3,'class'=>'textarea','style'=>'width:330px')); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table> 
                    </fieldset>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="reset" value="Reset"> | <?php echo $this->Form->submit('SEND', array('div' => false,'formnovalidate' => true));?></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table> 
               <?php print $this->Form->end();?> 
    </content>
    <div class="clear"></div>



Controller : 

    public  function send_money()
            {
                    $this->layout='agent';
                    if(empty($this->data) == false)
                    {
                            if($this->Senderinfo->save($this->data))
                            {

                                $this->Receiverinfo->save($this->data);
                                //$this->Session->setFlash('Data inserted successfully.');
                                //$this->redirect('send_money');
                            }

                            /*if($this->Receiverinfo->save($this->data))
                            {
                                //$this->Session->setFlash('Data inserted successfully.');
                                $this->redirect('send_money');
                            }
                            */
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //$this->set('errors', $this->Senderinfo->invalidFields()); 
                        //$this->set('errors', $this->Receiverinfo->invalidFields());       
                    } 

            }
```

I want to insert the records in two table with perfect validation.But my validation part in not working perfectly.That means when u see my view page u'll see sender information,receiver information,money which is wrapped by html legend.I want to do validation required field at a time after clicking submit button.In this code whats happening is that when i press submit button sender information validation is working but receiver information portion validation is not working.when i put any value in sender portion,that time receiver information portion's validation works only.What should i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all; apparently there is a 'relation' between the 'sender' and 'receiver' in your application, but NOT in your model/database definition. **Relying on the 'auto-incrementing' ID of your database (e.g. receiver 1 and sender 1 belong together) is not reliable**. Auto-incrementing IDs **will** come 'out of sync' between both tables and you will end up with a situation where `'receiver 123'` should actually be 'connected' to `'sender 125'`.

If I understand correctly what this form does, is create a 'money transaction' in the database. Sender and Receiver should (in this case) probably **not** be stored in separate databases, unless you're going to offer an option to 'pick' an existing sender/receiver from a list.

In both situations there should be a table/model in your application that 'connects' the two, otherwise you will just have a random list of people 'sending' and 'receiving' money, but *no way* to know *which* person wants to send money to *which* recipient

If you're not going to 're-use' the senders/receivers, than a correct database-design should be something like:

```
id| sender_name | sender_email | sender_address | receiver_name | receiver_email | receiver_address
1 | Amid        | 1@1.com      | Parkstreet     | SOS           | 2@2.com        | park 1
```

I would name this table 'money transfers' and the model 'Moneytransfer'

Having both in 1 model will simplify the validation and will guarantee that both sender and receiver info is present and correct.

**If you really want to manually save two separate records** (Based on my explanation above, I would strongly advise you to *not* do this) you should do this;

- validate both records manually via `$this->Mymodel->validates($data)`
- enclose both saves in a transaction and rollback if one of them fails

More information on manually validating inside your controller can be found here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html

More information on using transactions in CakePHP can be found here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/transactions.html

**[update]**

Browsing further through your 'form', there 'seems' to be a 'transaction' model as well?
***If* this is the case** and the Model-relations are properly defined in CakePHP, you will be able to save all *related* records using Model::saveAssociated(). This will also enclose all saves in a transaction (atomic)

See here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array